# Eclipse Luna splits editor on tab click. How to disable?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I moved from eclipse Kepler to eclipse Luna a few weeks ago. And it works quite nicely, i hardly notice the change which is a good thing.

The only thing that bugs me is that sometimes when i click on a file tab the editor goes into split mode. It only happens rarely, i suspect I'm doing some mouse gesture which splits the editor.

Is it possible to turn this mouse gesture off, or if it isn't a mouse gesture: is it possible to disable the splitting feature?

Answer (score 0):

Unbind the commands[**Toggle spit editor(Horizontal) and Toggle spit editor(Vertical)**] in `Windows > Preferences > General > keys` to disable the split editor feature.

Comment: Cheers for the reply! I just gave it a try, but it only disables the keys used to split the editor. With the mouse, which was the original problem, splitting still works. But i will give it some time, maybe disabling the keys does solve my problem.

Comment: Are you holding any key(s) while clicking mouse button. Where are you clicking?. I am not able to split the editor with mouse. Update how are you splitting the editor with mouse.

Comment: Nope, no keys pressed, to split the edit area with mouse simply click and drag the tab of a editor downwards, the split feature will appear. It is weird cause I'm quite sure I'm not dragging when the edit area spontaneous splits. That is why i suspected i did some mouse gesture thingy.

Comment: animated screen-cast/video is helpful here. I think you mis understood rearranging editors with spit editor look at here http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tips/platform_tips.html?cp=0_5_0#Workbench